# How to debug angular2 seed project in PhpStorm/WebStorm?

Tags: angular, debugging, phpstorm, webstorm

Angular2 is written in TypeScript.

I'm using [Angular2 seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed) and I can't get PhpStorm (WebStorm) to debug it - it's not stopping on breakpoint in `.ts` files.

Ho to do it?

Now I'm using `JavaScript Debug` with `http://localhost:8080` as URL - no breakpoints :/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To debug in WebStorm, you need to make sure to generate the sourcemaps. To do this, open `angular2-seed\webpack.config.js` and add

```
devtool: 'source-map',
```

to webpack configuration; then create javaScript debug run configuration with `http://localhost:8080/` URL, and add the following `Remote URL` mapping for the project root directory

```
webpack:///.
```

Now, start your server with `npm start`; once the server is started, run the configuration described above in debugger by pressing Debug

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Chrome, write in your code ( where you want to break ):

```
debugger;
```

Open browser, hit F12 ( developer console ), than refresh page. Execution of your app should stop on that command.

*Note, your tslint ( if you use that ) may complain of using debugger command. Edit your tslint.json file and put no-debugger to be true*

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"Angular batarang"** tool for debugging

Comment: this answer can be added as a comment. provide more information in you have it so

Comment: Would it be rather batarangle for Angular2? ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Putting breakpoints into your TypeScript files and executing step by step processing in them is possible within Chrome Dev Tools.

Did you make a try?

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Comment: I know that chrome has debugger but I'm using phpStorm as IDE and asking for phpStorm. But thanks for reply

Comment: What I simply mean is that you can always execute the client side application (angular2) within a browser (chrome for example) and so use its built-in debugger...